# ionic Property 'catch' does not exist on type 'PromiseLike<void>'

Tags: typescript, ionic2

im getting a Typescript Error

> Property 'catch' does not exist on type 'PromiseLike<void>'.

using ionic, in the `catch` line below:

```
sendrequest(req: connreq) {
  var promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    this.firereq
      .child(req.recipient)
      .push({
        sender: req.sender,
      })
      .then(() => {
        resolve({ success: true });
      })
      .catch(err => {
        resolve(err);
      });
  });
}
```

Comment: Which firebase library are you using (what is `this.firereq`)?

Answer (score 0):

You can resolve the issue by using set() with push(). Use following code, It will resolve your issue:

```
sendrequest(req: connreq) {
  var promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    this.firereq
      .child(req.recipient)
      .push().set({
        sender: req.sender,
      })
      .then(() => {
        resolve({ success: true });
      })
      .catch(err => {
        resolve(err);
      });
  });
}
```